# What is the actual value to be passed in boto3 for creating the rules for ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, botocore

I am working on a use case where the user is tring to create the service in a aws which will hit the service from the Elastic Load balancer. The load-balancer exists already, but I would like to create the new rule for the ELBv2 using the boto3 create/update rule method. The documentation has the information on schema level. But I am not sure where to edit the valid rule in the json.

```
Conditions=[
    {
        'Field': 'string',
        'Values': [
            'string',
        ],
        'HostHeaderConfig': {
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
        'PathPatternConfig': {
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ]
        }]
```

If the load-balancer has the url: **example.com** - I would like create the rule as "XYZ" where can I pass these XYZ in the above dictionary. So that, if I try to access the **example.com/XYZ**, the url should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client = boto3.client('elbv2')
listener_arn = 'listener ARN'
response = client.describe_rules(ListenerArn=listener_arn)
is_rule_exists = False
for rule in response['Rules']:
    conditions = rule['Conditions']
    for condition in conditions:
        for value in condition['Values']:
            if value == 'file_pattern_you_want_to_choose':
                is_rule_exists = True
            else:
                print("Nope")

condition = [
    {
        'Field': 'path-pattern',
        'Values': [
            'path pattern value',
        ]
    }
]
actions = [{
    'Type': 'forward',
    'TargetGroupArn': 'target group arn for your instance'
}]

priority = 10

if is_rule_exists:
    print('Do Nothing. Or Else create the rule')
    client.modify_rule(ListenerArn=listener_arn, conditions=condition, actions=actions)
else:
    print('Create the rule')
    client.create_rule(ListenerArn=listener_arn, Conditions=condition, Actions=actions, Priority=priority)
```

The above is the python code snippet, I have used to fetch the file path pattern and it checks if the rule exists. If not, it will create the rule. Or else, you can modify the rule.